# QUERY+VLOOKUP+IMPORTRANGE w/ Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I need to perform a VLOOKUP of a variable on Workbook A to find info in Workbook B, hence the IMPORTRANGE. I also need that VLOOKUP to filter based on certain criteria within Workbook B. I've been trying to make QUERY work for me, but it doesn't seem to work with VLOOKUP. I know that FILTER also exists, but I have yet to make FILTER work with VLOOKUP either.

Example:

```
VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet2!C:AH"),27,0)
```

There are duplicate variants to be found in Workbook B/Sheet2 for the variable A2, so i need to set a condition based on Column 24 of Workbook B/Sheet2 to only return data if Column 24 contains the string "FinishProduct".
I hope this isn't super easy and I'm just being an idiot. Look forward to the help!!!

New Attempt:

```
QUERY(
  IMPORTRANGE(
    "1yLZ3H-tW1QaW0fDsK3kb_B96kT9-fV2We15-9KZyTGg",
    "TS Inventory!C:AC"
  ),
  "Select Col27 Where Col1='"&A2:A&"' AND Col22='FinishProduct'"
)
```

Still didn't work. Produced something but not what I wanted.

Comment: hard to understand what you want! share a minimal reproducible example, explain the input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet2!C:AH")}, 
 "where Col22='FinishProduct'", 0), 27, 0)
```

Comment: This was the solution!! Almost. 


=VLOOKUP(A2, QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet2!C:AH")}, 
 "where Col22='FinishProduct'", 0), 27, 0)
                                                   ^
                                                     This zero doesn't need to be there. 
Thank you sooooooooooo much. This is going to save me soo much time in my reports.